# Internal storage sd read in laptop: where are the files?

Tags: sd-card, internal-sd

I am trying to read in a laptop my micro sd card (which was used as internal storage), through a  SD card adapter. Goal is to access to my pictures.

On the laptop (using Linux), I see some folders, but none of them contains the pictures. Why am I not able ot access the files themselves? Is there some encryption going on?

The micro sd structure looks like this on Ubuntu:

```
 ── Android
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── com.android.vending
│   │   │   └── files
│   │   ├── com.google.android.apps.docs
│   │   │   └── cache
│   │   ├── com.google.android.music
│   │   │   └── files
│   │   ├── com.motorola.MotGallery2
│   │   │   └── cache
│   │   └── com.skype.raider
│   │       └── cache
│   └── media
│       └── com.motorola.MotGallery2
└── LOST.DIR
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SD cards used as internal storage on Marshmallow devices are encrypted, you cannot read them in a computer, or any other device under normal conditions.

There are articles about how to extract the encryption key from the phone and use it to mount the encrypted file system in Linux, but it is still not perfect. https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html